# Is it possible to get the ID attribute from a hyperlink url?

Tags: php, http

I am wondering if it is possible to get the ID attr from a hyperlink URL such as: https://example.com/?product=foo#addonTab (#addonTab) in a PHP script using $_SERVER global variable when a request comes from the browser.

Comment: The fragment (the part after the hash sign) is client-side only. It is never passed to the server.

Comment: The only way I can think of getting this server-side, is using Javascript to pass it to the backend.

Comment: Do you already have the URL in some string in PHP somehow, or are you asking how to get it from the current URL in your code? If it's in a string, then you can use `parse_url()` (as @LexLustor shows in the answer below) but if it's from the current URL, then PHP won't be able to see it for the reasons @Phylogenesis points out. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for pointing that out.
Yes, you are correct about getting it from the browser. I have updated the question as well.

Comment: As mentionen the, `#` and anything after will not be sent to PHP so it won't exist in the `$_SERVER`-variable. The `#` is called a _hash_ and is only accessible from the client. If you need it in the back end, you need to fetch it using JS `location.hash` and then send it to PHP using Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Edit (Sept 7, 2021)

The answer is : **it is not possible to access fragment identifier server-side**.

The fragment identifier is allowed in HTTP specification but to represent a sub-resource, a location inside the resource adressed by the URI.

According to Wikipedia (article [URI_fragment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment)), emphasis mine:

> The fragment identifier functions differently to the rest of the URI: its processing is **exclusively client-sided** with no participation from the web server, though the server typically helps to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the processing of fragments.
> When an agent (such as a web browser) requests a web resource from a web server, the agent sends the URI to the server, **but does not send the fragment**. Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the resource according to the document type and fragment value

Digging into the specification itself, I think that I have found the relevant part of it regarding the subject, again, emphasis mine :

> As such, the fragment identifier is **not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI**; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself **is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent**, regardless of the URI scheme.

## Original accepted answer :

The segment of the url you referring to is called [*fragment*](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5).

**Assuming that you already have access to the url as a string server-side**, you can easily parse it in PHP with the [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function, to which you pass your url as a parameter.

```php
parse_url('https://example.com/?product=foo#addonTab')
```

The result is an associative array containing each part of the url.

```php
array(5) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(5) "https"
  ["host"]=>
  string(11) "example.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(1) "/"
  ["query"]=>
  string(11) "product=foo"
  ["fragment"]=>
  string(8) "addonTab"
}
```

This function accepts a second parameter (*component*) where you can specify the part you require : therefore the function will return a string instead of an associative array.

According to the doc, components can be specified with the following built-in PHP constants : `PHP_URL_SCHEME`, `PHP_URL_HOST`, `PHP_URL_PORT`, `PHP_URL_USER`, `PHP_URL_PASS`, `PHP_URL_PATH`, `PHP_URL_QUERY` or `PHP_URL_FRAGMENT`.

Your usage would be :

```php
parse_url('https://example.com/?product=foo#addonTab', PHP_URL_FRAGMENT)
```

Be aware that *fragment* entry doesn't contain the `#` character.

Here is an online example : https://ideone.com/ZiZGwd

Comment: Just a note, this works well if you already have the full URL in a string somehow, but it won't work if you're trying to get the fragment from the current URL (since PHP don't get the `#` part of the URL at all). The OP is very unclear about this, so this may or may not work for them.

Comment: I didn't find the question unclear so I answered it : parsing an url in a PHP script. However, your comment here and in the question made me wonder. I may delete my answer or change it if it is not relevant to OP's (real) problem.

Comment: I think that if you just mention that, then it should answer the OP's question either way.

Comment: @cornel Following your discussion with Magnus Eriksson
 and you precising your question, I updated my answer, even if you accepted if before. Feel free to change your vote if needed.